# executing method once if there is multiple instances

Tags: javascript

I have a question, say that we have a board that is 500 y's tall, and we have a falling block that grabs that y and moves it to its own variable that changes the static y to a dynamic y that is now the y of the falling block, if when that block reaches 350 y on on the board it executes the code in  the if statement just once. the issue I am having is it is doing it for each y under 350, all the way to 500.

Below is just a small snippet of what I have, before this the default y is set to be at 135, and dy is set to -1; then y is set to y-dy inside the function, and the block is falling. in the if statement it checks if it is past a certain point, and then logs a message, but the issue is, for each point y is past 351 it logs the message, i just want it to do it once, is there a way I can use == or should i set a variable to y or something like that.

Here's the code.

```
var y = y-dy;
curVal = 0;
ctx.drawImage(block,x,y,50,50);

if(y > 351 && x < 64){
console.log('RED!');
//set the value of the block here
curVal = curVal + randNum;
console.log(curVal);
}
```

and if i cant do that, is there a way i just let the event happen **once?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a global variable:

```
var flag = true;
```

And use it like this:

```
if(y > 351 && x < 64 && flag){
    flag = false;
    ...
```

This will ensure that the `if` block is executed at most once.